# Having trouble with writing a method using NSDictionary to convert variables to numbers

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

A little background:
I'm teaching myself how to program iOS. So I'm a beginner.
I just can't wrap my head around this problem.

I have a method that's basically supposed to take a variable on a button, pass that variable over to my variable conversion method.

The variable conversion method is just supposed to go through a predefined `NSDictionary` and basically search for the variable and return the associated value.

The display is then updated with that associated variable.

i.e. if the value of x is 2, then when I press x, the screen should just say 2.
I'm just trying to teach myself NSDictionary and all that, so any help will be great.

```
- (IBAction)variablePressed:(id)sender {
    NSDictionary *values = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], @"x",
                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:4], @"y",
                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:6], @"z", nil];
    double newValue = [self.brain convertVariable:[sender currentTitle] usingVariableValues:values];

  // NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newValue]);
}
```

The code crashes on the line with the `NSLog`. I commented it out because I can't get it working.

Comment: Yes, please narrow it down to a specific question. Nobody is going to wade through your entire project and guess at what you're having trouble with.

Comment: Of course,
There is only a single method that I need help with. The method located in CalculatorViewController.m
The name of the method is -(IBAction)variablePressed (line 62).


The program appears to crash at line 69 which has been commented out. I attempted to use NSLog to see wether the variable newValue was assigned a value, but I could get the variable to print with NSLog

Comment: try %f instead of %d.  d stands for digit not double.  The error is EXC_BAD_ACCESS right?

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I can't believe that I made such a dumb mistake!
Everything works now.

Comment: Link works, sorry messed around with Github a little bit.

Just for future reference, %g will get rid of trailing zeroes. I believe %f is for float? I maybe wrong.

Comment: okay, I removed the downvote. Nex time, please put your code into the question. A link to github won't cut it. Because obviously you will fix the bug in your code. And then your question just doesn't make sense anymore.

Comment: @borrrden You should post your comment as a (slightly) longer-winded answer so that the poster can accept it :)

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, I'm new here, so I'll get the hang of it soon enough.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the NSLog statement to the following...

```
NSLog(@"newValue is %f", newValue);
```

NSLog performs argument substitution, so there is no need for stringWithFormat.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the correct substitution for your variable in your stringWithFormat.  It is trying to read it as a digit.  This results in the incorrect number of bytes being read from that memory location (or so I assume), and a crash (this part is not an assumption xD).  %d looks like it should mean "double" but it actually means "digit" (int, short, etc).  Change it to %f (=float) and it will be just fine.

**EDIT** As noted in the other answer, NSLog works in the same way as stringWithFormat (it takes the format string and arguments directly).  You don't need to pass stringWithFormat to it.  In fact, doing that will cause a compiler warning about a potentially insecure string.

Comment: Thank you for the help!
Let's say I want to set the display using

self.display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", newValue];

Is there another way to do this? Or am I doing this the correct way?

Secondly, is %g ok? I notice that %f leaves in trailing zeroes.

Comment: %g is also fine, here is the reference guide from Apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265